# My Steam gives an "Failure to start game Unknown Error" on games that are already installed and I've played it earlier in the day

Tags: steam

Earlier today, I played Sonic and All Stars Racing Transformed multiple times between 8:00 AM and 2:00 PM. At around 3-ish it gave me the failure to start game error. I tried all the other games and they all had the same error. All of these games have been played before and are installed on the computer. The internet was working and Steam was online, as I had a notification pop up that one of my friends was playing TF2

Comment: Have you tried restarting Steam or your PC?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with games, especially Skyrim, and anything I'd played that day would no longer work.  I ended up having to restart my PC each time it would appear otherwise I couldn't start my games.  Typically I would get it if Skyrim crashed or I cancelled the loading sequence before it was finished.

This blurb is taken from the Steam forums (granted is for a separate game):

> Solution 1. Run the game as administrator
>   Find the file SalvationProphecy.exe
>
> On my computer (win7, 32-bit), it is located here:
>           C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\SalvationProphecy\bin\release\SalvationProphecy.exe
>   Right click on it
>   Select "Run as Administrator"
>   If that doesn't work, go on to the next test.
>
> Solution 2. Run steam as administrator
>   Exit steam completely: (top left menu) -> Steam -> Exit
>   Wait a few seconds for it to finish shutting down
>   Right click the steam icon
>   Select "Run as Administrator"
>   Try running the game normally
>   If that doesn't work, go on to the next test.
>
> Solution 3. Verify the integrety of game cache
>   Run Steam
>   Right click on Salvation Prophecy
>   Click "Properties"
>   Click the "LOCAL FILES" tab
>   Click "VERIFY INTEGRITY OF GAME CACHE..."
>   Wait until it is done
>   Try running the game normally.
>   If that doesn't work, go on to the next test.
>
> Solution 4. Check your antivirus settings
>   I can't give precise instructions here, because it depends on your antivirus program. But sometimes they can block a program from launching. There has been a problem reported with Avast.
>
> Solution 5. Restart the computer
>   The old classic, always worth a shot.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/app/248450/discussions/0/792923683573395036/

Answer (score 0):

- Please try out the steps shown on the [Steam troubleshooting page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8676-EFLX-7453&l=english&steamid=76561198049143381&errortype=EAppUpdateError&errorvalue=1).
- If this doesn't help, please look up if the task really is killed by entering the task manager.
- You can also try to start the game in the offline mode as shown [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3160-agcb-2555). (Please be aware that some applications needs to sync with Steam by time.)
- Restarting your PC always is an option.
- If Steam is set as auto start, please remove it, and start it manually.
- Please check whether games are blocked by a firewall or similar programmes.
- At last, you can reinstall Steam, too.

Check if the problem occurs on other machines too. Doing so, you can ensure that the problem is specific to your current machine, or to the software itself. Either way, you can always create [a new ticket](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php) to get some support by Valve employees.